# Update root in XML after the childs got processed

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

Related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38974656/3316077) I managed to accomplish what's been asked with the following snippet:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def read_xml():
    with open('test.xml') as xml_file:
        return xml_file.read()


xml_file = read_xml()

root = ET.fromstring(xml_file)
pmt_infs = root.find('.//CstmrCdtTrfInitn').findall('PmtInf')
print(pmt_infs)

nodes = []
for node in pmt_infs:
    children = list(node)
    nodes.append(children)

xml_stuff = [None] * len(nodes)
to_remove = []

for first, *column in zip(*nodes):
    for index, item in enumerate(column, 1):
        if 'CdtTrfTxInf' in item.tag:
            xml_stuff[index] = item
            continue

        if first.tag == item.tag and first.text == item.text and index not in to_remove:
            to_remove.append(index)

for index in to_remove:
    pmt_infs[0].append(xml_stuff[index])
for index in to_remove[::-1]:
    pmt_infs.pop(index)

print(pmt_infs)
```

Now, what the above piece of code does it's exactly what I asked in the previous question:

> I would like to move the whole `<CdtTrfTxInf></CdtTrfTxInf>` to the
>   first `<PmtInf></PmtInf>` and remove the whole `<PmtInf></PmtInf>` that
>   I've taken `<CdtTrfTxInf></CdtTrfTxInf>` from.

The above has been done, but I have a small problem. Initially, I get the `root` from the file. And now, I want to update it with the new data. The problem is that I don't know how to add the first part of the XML in the new file and then, append the `pmt_infs` to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <other_tags>a</other_tags> <!--here there might be other nested tags inside <other_tags></other_tags>-->
            <other_tags>b</other_tags> <!--here there might be other nested tags inside <other_tags></other_tags>-->
            <other_tags>c</other_tags> <!--here there might be other nested tags inside <other_tags></other_tags>-->
        </GrpHdr>
        <!-- here should be the <PmtInf> that's been processed above -->
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Can somebody give me some hints ?

---

LE: As requested, I'll add here the desired results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <other_tags>a</other_tags> 
            <other_tags>b</other_tags>
            <other_tags>c</other_tags> 
        </GrpHdr>

        <PmtInf>
            <things>d</things> 
            <things>e</things> 

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <things>f</things> 
            <things>g</things> 

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Now the output looks like that because:

- looking at the `<PmtInf></PmtInf>` sections (which are three), we can see that:

  1. if we compare the `<things>` from first `<pmtinf>` and things from the second `<pmtinf>` we can see they are not the same (`d != f`, `e != g`) so we move on to the next `<pmtinf>`; If we compare the first `<pmtinf>` `<things>` with the third ones, they are also the same, so we leave the first `<pmtinf>` as it is.
  2. we go to the second `pmtinf` section and compare `things` from it with `things` from the third `pmtinf` (they are the same). That said, we take the `CdtTrfTxInf` part from the third `pmtinf`, add it to the second `pmtinf` at the end and remove the third `pmtinf` completely.

Imagine this as a list of lists (which in fact, that's what they are):

```
[[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3]]
```

*Where*:
a = first `<things>` tag from a `<PmtInf>`
b = second `<things>` tag from a `<PmtInf>`
c = `< CdtTrfTxInf>` tag from a `<PmtInf>`

In my example:

`a1!=a2` and `b1!=b2` => we can move to the next sublist (if they would've been the same, the list would look like:

```
[[a1, b1, c1, c2],[a3, b3, c3]]
```

`a1!=a3` and `b1!=b3` => we can go to the second sublist and compare it with all the sublists after it

`a2==a3` and `b2==b3` => they are the same so we will now have:

```
[[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2, c3]]
```

As it is, my result will only be:

```
<PmtInf>
    <things>d</things>
    <things>e</things>

    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <!-- other nested tags here -->
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
</PmtInf>

<PmtInf>
    <things>f</things>
    <things>g</things>

    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <!-- other nested tags here -->
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <!-- other nested tags here -->
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
</PmtInf>
```

But I need it to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <other_tags>a</other_tags> 
            <other_tags>b</other_tags>
            <other_tags>c</other_tags> 
        </GrpHdr>

        <PmtInf>
            <things>d</things> 
            <things>e</things> 

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <things>f</things> 
            <things>g</things> 

            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Comment: *update it with the new data*...what new data? Where is such data?

Comment: @Parfait semantically, there's no new data. The correct way would be _the modified data_ which is in pmt_infs

Comment: @Dex'ter - I'll await clarification from OP. My italics was verbatim from OP's post. If he/she can post desired results then that would be helpful. Even better and this goes for previous post, is providing a snippet of actual XML as `<other_tags>`/`<things>` may/may not repeat and are needed for proper referencing.

Comment: @Parfait added extra information. Please ask anything you don't understand. I'm having hard times with this for 4 days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the transformation language used to manipulate XML documents. Specifically, your re-ordering actually requires the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), a 1.0 procedure to index the XML document with a certain key and group child data accordingly (in 2.0 an easier `<xsl:for-each-group>` can be used). Here, the key used is the concatenation of the `<things>` nodes under `<PmtInf>`.

Python's third-party module, `lxml`, can run XSLT 1.0 scripts using the [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/) processor. Of course, Python can also call external processors like [Saxon and Xalan](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) which these processors can run 2.0, even newer 3.0 scripts. In this solution, no `for` looping or `if` logic is needed. Also, use of `<xsl:key>` is more efficient as you create a hash table on the document content.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <other_tags>a</other_tags>
            <other_tags>b</other_tags>
            <other_tags>c</other_tags>
        </GrpHdr>

        <PmtInf>
            <things>d</things>
            <things>e</things>
            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <things>f</things> 
            <things>g</things> 
            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>

        <PmtInf>
            <things>f</things> 
            <things>g</things> 
            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <!-- other nested tags here -->
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

**XSLT** Script *(save as a separate .xsl or .xslt file; adjust key @use and its later references to actual)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="pkey" match="PmtInf" use="concat(things[1], things[2])" />

  <xsl:template match="/Document">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CstmrCdtTrfInitn"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CstmrCdtTrfInitn"> 
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="GrpHdr"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="PmtInf[count(. | key('pkey', concat(things[1], things[2])))]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="things"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('pkey', concat(things[1], things[2]))">      
           <xsl:copy-of select="CdtTrfTxInf"/>       
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>

   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL SOURCES
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM SOURCE DOCUMENT
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# OUTPUT TO FILE   
xmlfile = open('Output.xml', 'wb')
xmlfile.write(newdom)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output** XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Document>
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <other_tags>a</other_tags>
      <other_tags>b</other_tags>
      <other_tags>c</other_tags>
    </GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
      <things>d</things>
      <things>e</things>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <!-- other nested tags here -->
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
    <PmtInf>
      <things>f</things>
      <things>g</things>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <!-- other nested tags here -->
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <!-- other nested tags here -->
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. Could you please check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169735/update-root-in-xml-after-the-childs-got-processed?noredirect=1#comment65687664_39169735) ? I tried running your transformation on my xml, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is the link to this very page? I almost sure the reason transformation does not work is you not using actual xml but this mock document of `<things>` and `<other_tags>` nodes. Specific elements are needed for the key. Try editing post with actual and leave out confidential info.